# POST not posting variables?

Tags: php

It isn't posting variables?
They both are php files but not sure if I should rename the one with no PHP code to .html?

HTML:

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="details" action="processed.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname">
        <input type="submit" value="Generate">
    </form>

</body>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
        $itemname = $_POST["itemname"];
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    TEST( <?php $itemname ?> )TEST

</body>
```

Comment: you forgot to echo. `<?php echo $itemname ?>`.

Comment: A file containing only HTML is *ok* to have a `.php` extension. The otherway around won't work without special server configs though

Comment: err... um echo perhaps?

Comment: *"not sure if I should rename the one with no PHP code to .html?"* - that's not where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the variable with an echo or a print, otherwise you won't see it :

```
TEST( <?php echo $itemname; ?> )TEST
```

or

```
TEST( <?= $itemname ?> )TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

No echo ??

```
 TEST( <?php echo  $itemname ?> )TEST
```

You should use `echo` or `print` to print the data